# Can't add listeners to buttons created by another button

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I'm a newbie at programming.

I have a button (Canciones) that creates multiple buttons in the empty div (to the right), but I can't add `EventListeners` to them, I cannot make it work. I think that maybe the Listeners are on, but they don't work 'cause they `"can't read property of undefined"`. I don't understand what's happening, but I wasted a lot of time trying to solve it by myself.

```
let canciones = [
    {
        nombre: "Heroes",
        portada: "img/album/davidBowieHeroes.jpg",
        audio: "music/davidBowieHeroes.mp3",
        autor: "David Bowie",
        album: "Heroes",
        genero: "Rock Pop"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Detroit Rock City",
        portada: "img/album/kissDestroyer.jpg",
        audio: "music/kissDetroitRockCity.mp3",
        autor: "Kiss",
        album: "Destroyer",
        genero: "Rock"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Bycicle Race",
        portada: "img/album/queenJazz.jpg",
        audio: "music/queenBycicleRace.mp3",
        autor: "Queen",
        album: "Jazz",
        genero: "Rock"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Livin' On A Prayer",
        portada: "img/album/bonJoviSlipperyWhenWet.jpg",
        audio: "music/bonJoviLivin'OnAPrayer.mp3",
        autor: "Bon Jovi",
        album: "Slippery When Wet",
        genero: "Rock"
    },
    {
        nombre: "I'm Just a Singer in a Rock and Roll Band",
        portada: "img/album/theMoodyBluesSeventhSojourn.jpg",
        audio: "music/theMoodyBluesI'mJustASingerInRockAndRollBand.mp3",
        autor: "The Moody Blues",
        album: "Seventh Sojourn",
        genero: "Rock"
    },
    {
        nombre: "London Calling",
        portada: "img/album/theClashLondonCalling",
        audio: "music/theClashLondonCalling.mp3",
        autor: "The Clash",
        album: "London Calling",
        genero: "Punk"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Master Of Puppets",
        portada: "img/album/metallicaMasterOfPuppets.jpg",
        audio: "music/metallicaMasterOfPuppets.mp3",
        autor: "Metallica",
        album: "Master Of Puppets",
        genero: "Heavy Metal"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Hangar 18",
        portada: "img/album/megadethRustInPeace.jpg",
        audio: "music/megadethHangar18.mp3",
        autor: "Megadeth",
        album: "Rust In Peace",
        genero: "Heavy Metal"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Some Might Say",
        portada: "img/album/oasisMorningGlory.jpg",
        audio: "music/oasisSomeMightSay.mp3",
        autor: "Oasis",
        album: "Morning Glory",
        genero: "Rock"
    },
    {
        nombre: "God Only Knows",
        portada: "img/album/theBeachBoysPetSounds.jpg",
        audio: "music/theBeachBoysGodOnlyKnows.mp3",
        autor: "The Beach Boys",
        album: "Pet Sounds",
        genero: "Rock"
    }
]

const nombreCancion = document.getElementById("nombreCancion");
const imgAlbum = document.getElementById("imgAlbum");
const cancion = document.getElementById("cancion");
const nombreAutor = document.getElementById("nombreAutor");
const albumCancion = document.getElementById("albumCancion");
const genero = document.getElementById("genero");
const cancionesA = document.getElementById("canciones");

var i = 0;

function boton1() {
    cancionesA.innerHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < canciones.length; i++) {
        let boton = document.createElement("button");   
        boton.innerText = canciones[i].nombre; 
        boton.setAttribute("class", "cancion");
        boton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            cambiarCancion(canciones);
        });
        cancionesA.appendChild(boton);
    }
}

function cambiarCancion() { 
        nombreCancion.innerText = canciones[i].nombre;
        imgAlbum.src = canciones[i].portada;
        cancion.src = canciones[i].audio;
        nombreAutor.innerText = canciones[i].autor;
        albumCancion.innerText = canciones[i].album;
        genero.innerText = canciones[i].genero;
}
```

the Listeners don't work.

Comment: Can you please also add your HTML to make it a complete and working example

Comment: You call `cambiarCancion(canciones)` but `function cambiarCancion()` does not take parameters. Is this correct?

Comment: Also if possible, please translate your variables in english.

Comment: You also use `canciones[i]` in `cambiarCancion` but what is `i` here?

Comment: Just to add to Ammesihel's comment, imagine someone gave you the task to maintain a code written in russian cyrillic...

Comment: @caramba I don't know how to do that, but i'll figure it out.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, that's correct! and the [i], is the "previous" [i] in the for, I mean, I know is kinda dumb, but I don't really know how to make it work because of the scope (global scope helped a little bit).

Comment: @Amessihel Yes, I was gonna do that, but I was so burned out...

Comment: @Roko C.Buljan don't exaggerate, but yes, you are right, I'll change it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution is to add *one* event listener to the *parent element* (cancionesA) instead and catch clicks from the child elements as they bubble up the DOM. This is known as [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). In your button loop you can assign an id to each button which you can then use to identify the button that was clicked.

```js
let canciones = [{"nombre":"Heroes","portada":"img/album/davidBowieHeroes.jpg","audio":"music/davidBowieHeroes.mp3","autor":"David Bowie","album":"Heroes","genero":"Rock Pop"},{"nombre":"Detroit Rock City","portada":"img/album/kissDestroyer.jpg","audio":"music/kissDetroitRockCity.mp3","autor":"Kiss","album":"Destroyer","genero":"Rock"},{"nombre":"Bycicle Race","portada":"img/album/queenJazz.jpg","audio":"music/queenBycicleRace.mp3","autor":"Queen","album":"Jazz","genero":"Rock"},{"nombre":"Livin' On A Prayer","portada":"img/album/bonJoviSlipperyWhenWet.jpg","audio":"music/bonJoviLivin'OnAPrayer.mp3","autor":"Bon Jovi","album":"Slippery When Wet","genero":"Rock"},{"nombre":"I'm Just a Singer in a Rock and Roll Band","portada":"img/album/theMoodyBluesSeventhSojourn.jpg","audio":"music/theMoodyBluesI'mJustASingerInRockAndRollBand.mp3","autor":"The Moody Blues","album":"Seventh Sojourn","genero":"Rock"},{"nombre":"London Calling","portada":"img/album/theClashLondonCalling","audio":"music/theClashLondonCalling.mp3","autor":"The Clash","album":"London Calling","genero":"Punk"},{"nombre":"Master Of Puppets","portada":"img/album/metallicaMasterOfPuppets.jpg","audio":"music/metallicaMasterOfPuppets.mp3","autor":"Metallica","album":"Master Of Puppets","genero":"Heavy Metal"},{"nombre":"Hangar 18","portada":"img/album/megadethRustInPeace.jpg","audio":"music/megadethHangar18.mp3","autor":"Megadeth","album":"Rust In Peace","genero":"Heavy Metal"},{"nombre":"Some Might Say","portada":"img/album/oasisMorningGlory.jpg","audio":"music/oasisSomeMightSay.mp3","autor":"Oasis","album":"Morning Glory","genero":"Rock"},{"nombre":"God Only Knows","portada":"img/album/theBeachBoysPetSounds.jpg","audio":"music/theBeachBoysGodOnlyKnows.mp3","autor":"The Beach Boys","album":"Pet Sounds","genero":"Rock"}];

const nombreCancion = document.getElementById("nombreCancion");
const cancionesA = document.getElementById("canciones");

function boton1() {

  // Create a document fragment to save on DOM hits
  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  // For each button
  canciones.forEach((current, index) => {
    let boton = document.createElement("button");   
    boton.innerText = current.nombre;

    // Add the index as a data attribute
    boton.dataset.id = index;
    boton.setAttribute("class", "cancion");

    // Append the button the fragment
    frag.appendChild(boton);
  });

  // Finally append the fragment to the parent element
  cancionesA.appendChild(frag)
}

// Add one event listener to the parent element
cancionesA.addEventListener('click', cambiarCancion, false);

function cambiarCancion(e) {

  // Destructure the id from the target element (the
  // button that was clicked)
  const { target: { dataset: { id } } } = e;
  nombreCancion.innerText = canciones[id].nombre;
}

boton1();
```

```html
<div id="canciones"></div>
<div id="nombreCancion"></div>
```

Further reading

- [`createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)
- [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Syntax)

Comment: You just saved my life, thank you very much. You have no idea how much I was suffering with this.